# Take photo and save original size

Tags: android

How can get photo from intent

`Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);`

in `onActivityResult` not in URI format but JPG,PNG orginal size and save it gallery.
Need JPG,PNG because after shot I adding watermark on it.

I don't know why after `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);` returned photo size from `2048x1536` is `256x192`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For saving the image in the gallery you have send a broadcast as shown in the code sample below.
2. If you need the image with orignal sizes you could simply catch the uri and set it to a ImageView directly. Although it is a good practice to scale it down and use a smaller version of your bitmap to avoid the OutOfMemory Exception.

   ```
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

       if(requestCode==CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
          if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
              saveToGallery(mImageUri);
              yourImageView.setImageURI(mImageUri);
         }  
      }
   }

   public void saveToGallery(Uri uri){
       sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,uri));
   }
   ```